# Read configuration values in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a robot framework test automation product that runs in a docker container. All the configurations for the project are written in a `.env` file and all works perfectly in the docker environment.

Wat I want is to run this project out side the docker environment(in my laptop using VS code or any other supported IDE). But I don't know how to set the configuration environment when I run the project out side the docker environment.

Can someone please tell me the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the soultion.

1.You create `.env` file as below and put all of your environment variables as below. This is the environment file that you are going to push in to the docker container.

```
HOST_ADDRESS="https://192.168.0.15"
DEFAULT_PORT="8056"
```

2.Create .yaml file called `LocalConfig.yaml` and place all your local configuration in that file as below.

```
LOCAL_HOST_ADDRESS: "https://192.168.0.10"
LOCAL_DEFAULT_PORT: "8055"
```

3.Create .resource file called `Config.resource` and read all the environment variables from the OS environment using `%` character and if the environment variable is not found in the OS, you can set the default value which is defined in the `LocalConfig.yml` file as below.

```
*** Settings ***
Variables  LocalConfig.yaml

*** Variables ***
${CONFIG_HOST_ADDRESS}    %{HOST_ADDRESS=${LOCAL_HOST_ADDRESS}}
${CONFIG_PORT}            %{DEFAULT_PORT=${LOCAL_DEFAUL_PORT}}
```

4.Then you can reference this `Config.resource` file in any of your `.robot` files and retrieve the configuration values.

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        ../Config.resource

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Retrieve env variable Test
Log To Console  ${CONFIG_HOST_ADDRESS}
```